# Wants to force a function of a specific type, but want to have a default value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to force a function of a specific type, but want to have a default value for some functions.

And I tried with simple code like below

```
type MyFunc = (str: string) => number;

const myAFunc: MyFunc = (str) => Number(str);
const myBFunc: MyFunc = (str = '9999') => Number(str);

myAFunc('a');
myAFunc(); // wants to occur error
myBFunc('b');
myBFunc(); // wants to NOT occur error
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigCgM7ACcAuKfAgS2QHMBKTAPimUQFsAjCAgbgCgfUA9snxQWIAIJI0JOFPRY8hOhkYA5VhwKKCNXoOHBRIAEJyZCFPJxlMUAOQBOJw7vK1Gztt18xky9jsAQ1deXzlsXSgAeiioAHdA5GBcKGABKAFUVEQCKE4CAQIeMVN-OzYQ4pNwyJj4xOTU9NUAeQAVDKycvIICgiA

But it's not working.

Is there some way to solve it?

Comment: You need to declare two separate function types because they should behave in a different way if argument is not provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A and B func has different types, don't force them into same type:

```
type MyAFunc = (str: string) => number;
type MyBFunc = (str?: string) => number;

const myAFunc: MyAFunc = (str) => Number(str);
const myBFunc: MyBFunc = (str = '9999') => Number(str);

myAFunc('a');
myAFunc(); // wants to occur error
myBFunc('b');
myBFunc(); // wants to NOT occur error
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way not to declaring the types by dividing them all up like this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbIIxQF4oAKAOnIEMAnAcwGcAuKAbWUQFsAjCKgGijrAqGZDX6csWADYQKyALoBKQgD4BQkTQDcAKFCRYCFOmzIATIRLlS1ek1YdufdcNHjJMuQH4lql5t19aDgkNEwcAGZLMkpaRhY2Lh5+QVcaL3dpWWQfZQI1VICdHVQcQSh2EFwmEONwvGiKcX5UPLUAbx0obqgMADMSVqgqCGBEKmQoCigAaihOXR7h0fHJgHI13QBfXR1K3GJcAAZ+NcLRNf4hRAhFXdLkcsqzGqMw0wsiYib5lss+ihSOi3PydJb9QbKEZjCZTWbzRY9aGrKAbba7Z6HE6o840NZ3YoPJ4gCKvUImSKNcSWNYAEwgAMQUmA-gufyIAKBIPyUDBPQhxCGyNh0zmCy6SJWsLROh2xUqESxBKAA

Comment: if you don't define function types (MyAFunc, MyBFunc), it will work with a little change: const myAFunc = (str: string) => Number(str); Typescript will find out the actual types of both functions from function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it optional to pass anything to the function, add a ? for parameter in the type.

```
type MyFunc = (str?: string) => number;

const myAFunc: MyFunc = (str) => Number(str);
const myBFunc: MyFunc = (str = '9999') => Number(str);

myAFunc(); // NaN
myBFunc(); // 9999
```